# Using Unicode inside R's expression() command

Tags: windows, r, unicode

I'm using `expression()` in R plots in order to get italicized text. But it appears as if I cannot use Unicode symbols inside `expression` outside of ASCII characters. Is there some way I can work around this? My goal is to get the `fi` ligature in various labels in my R barplots (together with italicized text).

I'm using R for Windows version 3.0.2.

```
CairoPDF(file = "Ligature1.pdf")
plot.new()
text(x =.5, y = .5, labels = "ﬁ", family = "Times New Roman")
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
CairoPDF(file = "Ligature2.pdf")
plot.new()
text(x =.5, y = .5, labels = expression(paste(italic(m), "u", "ﬁ", italic(m), sep = "")), family = "Times New Roman")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine on Debian / R 3.0.2 - [`sessionInfo()`](http://pastebin.com/p25qReW7)

Comment: Not able to reproduce on a Mac, either. The `paste` looks unnecessary. What do you see with `italic(m)*u*ﬁ*italic(m)`?

Comment: @DWin: Exactly the same as in my question.

Comment: My answer to your other question should be helpful then.

Comment: Seems like the answer here as well is that R for Windows is having issues with UTF-8.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Windows.  You can simplify the example down to this (using the ordinary windows() device instead of pdf):

`plot.new() ; text(x =.5, y = .5, labels = expression(paste(italic(m), "u", "ﬁ", italic(m), sep = "")))`

Comment: So this issue still isn't fixed on Windows, apparently :(

Comment: This seems to be similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324872/rstudio-not-picking-the-encoding-im-telling-it-to-use-when-reading-a-file
I am curious is there is a solution there for you.

Comment: The OP asked for a work-around.  It is not too hard to produce the output that he requested under Windows by printing the `italic` part and the Unicode part separately. I am not posting as an answer because while it answers the original question,  I do not think it addresses the problem that the bounty was intended for.

Comment: @G5W it would also be nice to have italicized unicode.

Comment: Yes, all I seem to be able to get on my Windows system is a mixture of formatted ASCII and unformatted Unicode.  No formatted Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

You asked for a work-around.  That is all this is.   The italic part needs `expression`, but the "ﬁ" part does not,  so print them separately.

```
plot.new()
offset1 = strwidth(expression(paste(italic(m), "u")), units="figure")
text(x =.5, y = .5, labels = expression(paste(italic(m), "u", sep="")))
text(x =.5+offset1, y = .5, labels ="ﬁ")
offset2 = strwidth("ﬁ ")
text(x =.5+offset1+offset2, y = .5, labels = expression(italic(m)))
```

[image: formatted output]

But notice that something is not quite right about the spacing of the "ﬁ", so when I computed the width on the screen, I cheated and computed the width of "ﬁ "  (with an extra blank).  Without the extra spacing,  the second `italic(m)` overlapped the "ﬁ".

Not pretty, but it produces the desired result under Windows.