# Non italic greek letter in axis label without serif (MacOS)

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, fonts, typography

Is there an option to get a nice non italic greek letter (in my case "mu") in the axis label in `R` with `ggplot` and `sans-serif` applied?

This is how far I came:
[image: Overview of the hole plot]

Zoom of the output:
[image: Zoom picture of the mu]

Left "mu": If I look closely it doesn't fit properly:

- wrong `font` (I could deal with that)
- wrong `font` size

Right "mu":

- Just perfect, but I need it to be non-`italic` as it should be a unit

(Hint: In R-Studio preview window it is shown non-`italic`, but I need the PDF to be correct.)

Here the `R`-code:

```
library("ggplot2")

x <- seq(0,10,1)
y <- seq(0,1,0.1)
Data <- data.frame(x,y)

myPlot <- ggplot (Data, aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
geom_point() +
scale_x_continuous(expression(paste("[", mu, "m] and [µm]")))+
theme(text = element_text(size=12, family="sans")) +
theme_minimal(); myPlot

ggsave("Test.pdf", width = 16, height = 8, units ="cm", dpi = 1200)
```

Update I: Output of the `sessionInfo()` as it only appears on MacOs and not on Windows.

```
sessionInfo()
> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

> Matrix products: default
> BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

> locale:
> [1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

> other attached packages:
> [1] ggplot2_3.1.0

> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] Rcpp_0.12.19     withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.0 crayon_1.3.4     dplyr_0.7.7      R6_2.3.0        
>  [7] grid_3.5.1       plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0     pillar_1.3.0    
> [13] rlang_0.3.0.1    lazyeval_0.2.1   rstudioapi_0.8   bindrcpp_0.2.2   labeling_0.3     tools_3.5.1     
> [19] glue_1.3.0       purrr_0.2.5      munsell_0.5.0    yaml_2.2.0       compiler_3.5.1   pkgconfig_2.0.2 
> [25] colorspace_1.3-2 tidyselect_0.2.5 bindr_0.1.1      tibble_1.4.2
```

Comment: it is displayed in "non-italic" character in the pdf I got with your code...

Comment: Could you add output of `sessionInfo()` to your post, might be OS specific font issue?

Comment: On my windows machine it is non-`italic`as well.

Comment: I added the `sessionInfo()` in the code above.

Comment: Relevant, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890298/set-system-font-in-r-package-cairo-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mac OS and had the same issue. I got around it by saving my image as .eps file. Opening the .eps in preview still showed the units to be italic, but when opening in another image editor the units are non-italic.

Comment: Good hint. Sadly I need to import it into LaTeX and could not change it.