# Unicode character with superscript

Tags: r, unicode

I have an R plot with an axis of dimension squared Angstroms.

I can create the correct Angstrom symbol with Unicode like so:

```
plot.new()
text(x=0.5, y=0.8, labels="Interface area (\uc5)")
```

[image: Label with correct Angstrom symbol]

Both of my attempts to add a superscript result in errors:

```
plot.new()
text(x=0.5, y=0.6, labels=expression("Interface area ("*\uc5^2*")"))
# Error: unexpected input in "text(x=0.5, y=0.6, labels=expression("Interface area ("*\"

plot.new()
text(x=0.5, y=0.5, labels=expression("Interface area (\uc5"*^2*")"))
# Error: unexpected '^' in "text(x=0.5, y=0.5, labels=expression("Interface area (\uc5"*^"
```

Currently I am using a typographically incorrect hack:

```
plot.new()
text(x=0.5, y=0.7, labels=expression("Interface area ("*ring(A)^2*")"))
```

[image: Label with incorrect ring(A) symbol]

(Note that the ring over the A is too large)

Can I correct my syntax of expression() to use both backslash unicode characters and superscript?

*Note:* I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881553/using-unicode-inside-rs-expression-command) but it concerns direct use of the unicode character rather than the backslash representation.

Comment: doesn't replacing `ring(A)` with `'\uc5'` work in your latest attempt?

Comment: How about `text(x=0.5, y=0.7, labels=expression("Interface area ("*"\uc5"^2*")")) `

Comment: @rawr, this is why everyone tells you to stop posting answers as comments :)

Comment: touche, @DavidArenburg, touche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is probably:

```
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.7, labels = quote("Interface area " * (Å ^ 2)))
```